# postcss-autoreset is overriding font-family with the browser's default

Tags: css, postcss

I'm using [postcss-autoreset](https://github.com/maximkoretskiy/postcss-autoreset) which applies `all: initial;` to any element I style in my CSS files.

But, when I try to set the font of the `body` element only elements that I haven't styled in CSS will get the font. Elements I have styled revert to the browser's default. Which is very odd.

`all: initial;` seems to be overriding `font-face` because when I view in Chrome inspector it's showing as overridden.

As an example below all my elements on the page are displaying with the `Roboto` font, except for text within header which is using the browsers default.

**app.css**

```
@import "variables.css";
@import "header.css";
@import "footer.css";

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

**header.css**

```
header {
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

**config.js** (PostCSS CLI config.js file)

```
{
    "use": [
      "postcss-import",
      "postcss-cssnext",
      "lost",
      "rucksack-css",
      "postcss-autoreset",
      "postcss-font-magician"
    ],
    "input": "src/app.css",
    "output": "css/main.css",
    "local-plugins": true,
    "autoprefixer": {
      "browsers": "last 2 versions"
    }
}
```

Here is the output being produced by postcss:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: local("Roboto Thin Italic"),local(Roboto-ThinItalic),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/12mE4jfMSBTmg-81EiS-YVQlYEbsez9cZjKsNMjLOwM.eot?#) format("eot"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/12mE4jfMSBTmg-81EiS-Yfk_vArhqVIZ0nv9q090hN8.woff2) format("woff2"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/12mE4jfMSBTmg-81EiS-YRsxEYwM7FgeyaSgU71cLG0.woff) format("woff")
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local("Roboto Light Italic"),local(Roboto-LightItalic),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/7m8l7TlFO-S3VkhHuR0at2fQcKutQXcIrRfyR5jdjY8.eot?#) format("eot"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/7m8l7TlFO-S3VkhHuR0at44P5ICox8Kq3LLUNMylGO4.woff2) format("woff2"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/7m8l7TlFO-S3VkhHuR0at4bN6UDyHWBl620a-IRfuBk.woff) format("woff")
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Roboto Italic"),local(Roboto-Italic),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/OiNnAEwKzzJkQCr4qZmeq_esZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.eot?#) format("eot"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/vPcynSL0qHq_6dX7lKVByfesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format("woff2"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/1pO9eUAp8pSF8VnRTP3xnvesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff) format("woff")
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local("Roboto Medium Italic"),local(Roboto-MediumItalic),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/OLffGBTaF0XFOW1gnuHF0WfQcKutQXcIrRfyR5jdjY8.eot?#) format("eot"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/OLffGBTaF0XFOW1gnuHF0Y4P5ICox8Kq3LLUNMylGO4.woff2) format("woff2"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/OLffGBTaF0XFOW1gnuHF0YbN6UDyHWBl620a-IRfuBk.woff) format("woff")
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local("Roboto Bold Italic"),local(Roboto-BoldItalic),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/t6Nd4cfPRhZP44Q5QAjcC2fQcKutQXcIrRfyR5jdjY8.eot?#) format("eot"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/t6Nd4cfPRhZP44Q5QAjcC44P5ICox8Kq3LLUNMylGO4.woff2) format("woff2"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/t6Nd4cfPRhZP44Q5QAjcC4bN6UDyHWBl620a-IRfuBk.woff) format("woff")
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: local("Roboto Black Italic"),local(Roboto-BlackItalic),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/bmC0pGMXrhphrZJmniIZpWfQcKutQXcIrRfyR5jdjY8.eot?#) format("eot"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/bmC0pGMXrhphrZJmniIZpY4P5ICox8Kq3LLUNMylGO4.woff2) format("woff2"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/bmC0pGMXrhphrZJmniIZpYbN6UDyHWBl620a-IRfuBk.woff) format("woff")
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: local("Roboto Thin"),local(Roboto-Thin),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/PP2U5prMl9yvKSWVu6DtvPesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.eot?#) format("eot"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/2tsd397wLxj96qwHyNIkxPesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2) format("woff2"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/vzIUHo9z-oJ4WgkpPOtg1_esZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff) format("woff")
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local("Roboto Light"),local(Roboto-Light),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUffY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.eot?#) format("eot"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfVtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format("woff2"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfT8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format("woff")
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local(Roboto),local(Roboto-Regular),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/5YB-ifwqHP20Yn46l_BDhA.eot?#) format("eot"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/CWB0XYA8bzo0kSThX0UTuA.woff2) format("woff2"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/2UX7WLTfW3W8TclTUvlFyQ.woff) format("woff")
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local("Roboto Medium"),local(Roboto-Medium),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/RxZJdnzeo3R5zSexge8UUfY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.eot?#) format("eot"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/RxZJdnzeo3R5zSexge8UUVtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format("woff2"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/RxZJdnzeo3R5zSexge8UUT8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format("woff")
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local("Roboto Bold"),local(Roboto-Bold),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/d-6IYplOFocCacKzxwXSOPY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.eot?#) format("eot"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/d-6IYplOFocCacKzxwXSOFtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format("woff2"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/d-6IYplOFocCacKzxwXSOD8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format("woff")
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: local("Roboto Black"),local(Roboto-Black),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/mnpfi9pxYH-Go5UiibESIvY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.eot?#) format("eot"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/mnpfi9pxYH-Go5UiibESIltXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format("woff2"),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v15/mnpfi9pxYH-Go5UiibESIj8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format("woff")
}

header,
header .brand,
header nav,
header nav li,
header nav a,
header nav,
header nav ul,
header nav li,
body,
body {
  all: initial
}

header {
  background: #00AFEC;
  display: block
}

header .brand {
  width: 100%
}

header nav li {
  display: block;
  text-align: center
}

header nav a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px
}

@media (min-width: 361px) {
  header nav {
    width: 100%
  }
  header nav ul {
    float: right
  }
  header nav li {
    padding: 0 30px
  }
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postcss-autoreset` accepts `reset` option. By default it is just `all: initial`, which resets font. But I recommend to set `reset` in `all: initial; font-family: inherit; font-size: inherit`.

So in `postcss-autoreset` you should explicit show what properties you really want to inherit. And you could set some inherit properties by default in `reset` option.

Comment: Where do I provide the reset option? I am using `postcss-cli` and a `config.json` file as can be seen here: https://github.com/JamesTheHacker/Simplex

Comment: Here is a docs, how to set options for plugins in `config.json` https://github.com/postcss/postcss-cli#--config-c

Answer (score 1):

Normally the font-family is inherited by the parent element. So you may use a simple

```
html {
 font-family: Roboto;
}
```

to make the whole page use the Roboto font, even though there is no font-family explicitly defined for your elements - they simply inherit the value from their parent which is `html` (or in your example `body`).

If you are using postcss-autoreset, all elements styled by you, will get the `all: initial;` property, which resets the font-family. Therefore these elements will NOT have the Roboto `font-family`.

Btw, I wouldn't recommend you to use postcss-autoreset. I simply don't see the point in using it, as it doesn't do much (only add 1 prop/value) and it kinda breaks the css inheritance concept with it. In my opinion people should use postcss primarily to balance browser-inconsistencies. Plugins like [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) and [postcss-fixes](https://github.com/MattDiMu/postcss-fixes) (yeah, some self-promotion here) do a great job. If you want to replace your preprocessor sass/less/stylus, some other plugins like [precss](https://github.com/jonathantneal/precss) might make sense, but this whole concept of adding many micro-plugins, leading to unexpected behavior and output, is IMHO too unstable and causes more problems than it solves.